# Burger nav animation not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, navigation, nav, gsap, hamburger-menu

I'm having some difficulty getting my burger animation to work and release my navigation menu. I took the code directly as my instructor had it, since it worked in that html, but once I placed it in my code, everything seemed to be reversed? Now when the website loads, the nav menu is visible and if I click on the area the burger is in, it removes the nav but has the burger animate into an "X."

Here is the [link](http://mdonapelillustration.com/Marissa_Web3_Bananas/index.html) to the site I'm making.

Please bear in mind that I'm currently building the mobile format first before I begin anything else, so it may be helpful to shrink the page down!

Thank you!

Comment: Can you specify exactly how you want the animation to behave?

Comment: @tshimkus I have a burger svg, and I want the three lines of the burger, to meet in the middle to form one line and create an arrow on hover, then have the ring draw around it using DrawSVG on click, to have it form an arrow on hover again, and back to a burger on click. I've done this before and it worked fine but somehow, copying and pasting something so simple didn't seem to be the answer this go-around.